# File.exists? method returns true in a rails app controller but returns false in resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am working on a feature where I need to accept a file from a form submitted by user. After that I have to process the file in order to check if the specified values are correct and then update DB for the values specified in the CSV file.
To upload a file in rails application, I have used a technique similar to : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

And I am able to save the file in tmp folder on my app server. Now to do further processing, I want to pass the path of this file to a resque worker which will act upon this file. This worker is unable to find this file and the File.exists? return a false even though the same method returns true in the controller class. This is happening intermittently and I assume there is a race condition. Any suggestions as to what could be the issue and how to handle it?

[EDIT] : 
I realized what's going on. So, this was a staging environment and there are multiple app servers. The file is getting uploaded in the tmp folder in primary app server and the worker is searching for it in the secondary app server. This is the real cause of the trouble. Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: "Any ideas how to tackle this?" - yes, upload to a shared storage. Either a dedicated machine on your network or cloud storage like amazon s3.

Comment: This is exactly what we ended up doing. Thanks for pointing it out. Sorry! about reviving this dead thread. Just wanted to put this to closure.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your worker behind an `after_commit` callback. It might be because your worker started running even if the data hasn't persisted in your DB yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The worker is supposed to read the file and update the DB based on the values specified. Problem here is that the worker is not able to find the file that we previously saved in our controller.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. Have you tried adding `chomp` to the file path? Example: `File.exists?(file_path.chomp)`

Comment: Nope. But I can give it a try. The fact that its working intermittently for the same file is quite puzzling.